# Query a specific meta field from a joined table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a schema with the follow tables:

- **`posts`** (`id`,`title` etc)
- **`metas`** (`id`, `post_id` (foreign key to posts), `meta_key`, `meta_value`)

I want to query a list of all posts and also include a column containing a specific meta field. For this example let's say the meta field to get is `rating` - i.e. the `meta_key` is "rating".

For posts where no meta field with a "rating" key exists the field will be blank. Example of desired result:

```
| posts.id | posts.title | rating |
|----------|-------------|--------|
| 1        | Foo         | 3      |
| 2        | Bar         |        |
```

Here is a query I came up with which almost works. The problem with it is that if the post has other meta fields which are queried before 'rating', it results in nothing being returned for the meta field due to the GROUP BY directive.

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.title if(metas.meta_key = 'rating', metas.meta_value, '') as 'rating'

FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN metas ON posts.id = metas.post_id

GROUP BY posts.id;
```

I feel the conditional in the SELECT part of the query should somehow be incorporated into the JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

So, just look at the rating:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, max(m.meta_value) as rating
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     metas r
     ON p.id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key = 'rating'
GROUP BY p.id;
```

You can also do this using your logic by using an aggregation function such as `max()` before the expression.

Comment: Perfect, that does the trick. So it was my JOIN that was not quite right. No need to aggregate as there is a max of  1 `rating` per post.

Answer (score 1):

You are not outer-joining correctly.

You say: find metas for the post_id and if no such record exists then ...

But you want to say: find the meta for the post_id and key 'rating' ...

So:

```
SELECT 
  p.id, 
  p.title, 
  m.meta_value as rating
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN metas m ON m.post_id = p.id and m.meta_key = 'rating';
```

(I assume there is just one entry per post_id and meta_key in metas, so you don't need to aggregate anything here.)